Is it possible to make lambda with dynamic closure scope, depending on object
I have an idea to create something line Python logger but in C++.
I want to have a logger that can produce children. Each of them should log its name. All of them should write to the same instance of LogImpl that has an interface with a formatter function.
The crucial thing is a possibility to create children with nesting names.
I have written something like this (simplified example):
#include <iostream>

// Some third-party logger that I can't change
struct LogImpl {
    std::function<std::string(const std::string &msg)> formatter{nullptr};

    void write(const std::string &msg) const {
        const auto fMsg = formatter ? formatter(msg) : msg;
        std::cerr << fMsg << std::endl;
    }
};

// My wrapper
struct Logger {
    std::string name;
    LogImpl *impl{nullptr};

    explicit Logger(const std::string &name, LogImpl *impl) : name(name), impl(impl) {}

    std::shared_ptr<Logger> getChild(const std::string &name_) const {
        return std::make_shared<Logger>(name + "." + name_, impl);
    }

    void write(const std::string &msg) const {
        impl->write(msg);
    }

    void setRichFormat() const {
        impl->formatter = [&](const std::string &msg) {
            return name + "\t" + msg + "\n";
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    auto impl = new LogImpl();
    Logger rootLogger{"root", impl};
    auto childLogger = rootLogger.getChild("child");

    rootLogger.setRichFormat();

    rootLogger.write("ROOT MSG");
    childLogger->write("CHILD MSG");

    delete impl;
    return 0;
}

But it's obvious that in this case output will be:
root    ROOT MSG

root    CHILD MSG

And I think how to change this code to reach the result:
root    ROOT MSG

root.child  CHILD MSG

And I can't invent something to sort out this.

"But it's obvious that [...]" -- Sorry, it's not obvious to me. Then again, I have no motivation to slog through code that does not do what you want it to do in an attempt to figure out what you want it to do. That is probably a contributing factor... Any chance you could write out what you want in words?

I want to have a logger that can produce children. Each of them should log its name. All of them should write to the same instance of LogImpl that have an interface with formatter function.

The "children" part could use more explanation. What is a "child" of a logger? You want only one instance, which means only one object (and no derived classes). So a "child" is just its name? Or maybe you mean the logger can produce scopes (which would fit nicely with your "nesting names" terminology, as a nested scope is an established concept in the language).

It can be called scopes as well. I don't know which of terms is the best because each of them can point to different things.

What about this: You set the Logger instance in the callback of LogImpl each time before logging. To make this thread safe, you need a mutex, so beware of that.
struct Logger {
    std::string name;
    LogImpl *impl;

    struct Formatter {
        Logger* logger = nullptr;

        std::string operator()(std::string const& msg) const {
            assert(logger);
            return logger->name + "\t" + msg + "\n";            
        }
    };

    explicit Logger(const std::string &name, LogImpl *impl) : name(name), impl(impl) {}

    std::shared_ptr<Logger> getChild(const std::string &name_) const {
        return std::make_shared<Logger>(name + "." + name_, impl);
    }

    void write(const std::string &msg) const {
        static std::mutex writeMutex; 
        std::lock_guard writeLock(writeMutex);
        if (auto* target = impl->formatter.target<Formatter>()) {
            target->logger = this;
        }
        impl->write(msg);
    }

    void setRichFormat() const {
        impl->formatter = Formatter{ nullptr };
    }
};


If you need to use the same LogImpl you need to set the formatter in your Logger's write function so that each Logger instance can influence what LogImpl is doing. It's not pretty...
Here's an example where your Logger checks if formatter is not empty before calling its write function. If it's not empty, it's overwritten.
class Logger {
public:
    explicit Logger(const std::string& name, LogImpl& impl)
        : name(name), impl(&impl) {}

    std::shared_ptr<Logger> getChild(const std::string& name_) const {
        return std::make_shared<Logger>(name + '.' + name_, *impl);
    }

    void write(const std::string& msg) const {
        if (impl->formatter) setRichFormat(); // rich format set, overwrite it
        impl->write(msg);
    }

    void setRichFormat() const {
        impl->formatter = [&](const std::string &msg) {
            return name + '\t' + msg + '\n';
        };
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    LogImpl* impl{};
};

Demo

If you want to go this way, I guess you have no choice that each Logger instance has its own instance of LogImpl, i.e. you can't share the same impl between the root and child loggers.
So you can do the following:
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct LogImpl 
{
    std::function<std::string(const std::string &msg)> formatter{nullptr};

    void write(const std::string &msg) const {
        const auto fMsg = formatter ? formatter(msg) : msg;
        std::cerr << fMsg << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Logger {
    std::string name;
    std::shared_ptr<LogImpl> impl;

    std::shared_ptr<Logger> getChild(const std::string &name_)  
    {
        return std::make_shared<Logger>(name + "." + name_, std::make_shared<LogImpl>());
    }

    void write(const std::string &msg) const {
        impl->write(msg);
    }

    void setRichFormat() const {
        impl->formatter = [&](const std::string &msg) {
            return name + "\t" + msg + "\n";
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    auto impl = new LogImpl();
    Logger rootLogger{"root", std::make_shared<LogImpl>()};
    auto childLogger = rootLogger.getChild("child");

    rootLogger.setRichFormat();
    childLogger->setRichFormat();

    rootLogger.write("ROOT MSG");
    childLogger->write("CHILD MSG");

    return 0;
}

but you also will need to call setRichFormat on the child logger, which may not what you planned to.
Demo
Update: according to your remarks, if you need to keep LogImpl untouched, the solution is indeed to decorate the write method with some function that has access to information of Logger.
Note that this decoration has to be common to different instances of Logger, so here is a possible solution with a Singleton implementation for this decorator object (cleaner solutions surely exist):
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct LogImpl 
{
    std::function<std::string(const std::string &msg)> formatter{nullptr};

    void write(const std::string &msg) const {
        const auto fMsg = formatter ? formatter(msg) : msg;
        std::cerr << fMsg << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Logger 
{
    std::string name;
    LogImpl *impl{nullptr};

    static std::function<std::string(Logger const&, std::string const& msg)>& decorator()
    {
        static std::function<std::string(Logger const&, std::string const& msg)> instance = [](Logger const& logger, const std::string &msg) { return msg; } ;
        return instance;
    } 

    std::shared_ptr<Logger> getChild(const std::string &name_)  
    {
        return std::make_shared<Logger>(name + "." + name_, impl);
    }

    void write(const std::string &msg) const {
        impl->write(decorator()(*this,msg));
    }

    void setRichFormat()  
    {
        decorator() = [](Logger const& logger, const std::string &msg) { return logger.name + "\t" + msg + "\n"; };
    }
};

int main() {
    auto impl = new LogImpl();
    Logger rootLogger{"root", impl};

    auto childLogger = rootLogger.getChild("child");

    rootLogger.setRichFormat();

    rootLogger.write("ROOT MSG");
    childLogger->write("CHILD MSG");

    return 0;
}

Demo

Thanks! But is's important to use the same instance of LogImpl. It's just write to std::cerr in my example but in reality it's more complicated. I'm thinking about not to use formatter of LogImpl and write my own around raw write method

Ok, that's what I suspected !

Seems to me this is all a bit overblown.  Why not simply:
struct Logger {
    std::string name;

    explicit Logger(const std::string &name) : name(name) {}

    void write(const std::string &msg) const {
        std::cerr << name << "\t" << msg << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Logger rootLogger{"root"};
    Logger childLogger{"root.child"};

    rootLogger.write("ROOT MSG");
    childLogger.write("CHILD MSG");
}


Sorry, I've just edited the question and add an important detail: my logger is a wrapper around some third-party logger that I can't change. And all children should write to the same instance of this third-party logger.
